# How can I create a API in Flutter which would contain functions that can be accessible from other apps having the same key?

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

If a Flutter developer plans to develop a suite of apps which may use a set of functions or interfaces...Can that developer create a common place to store all the (assets,...,...) to save reduce the overall size of all the apk(s)?

That might add a common dependency to all the Flutter projects but is it somehow possible(on a native level, maybe)...

Note: I know that `intent` can be used for this purpose, but I to use this methodology in a more integrated way

Comment: Here is no such a possibility as far as I know. Even every Flutter application is being packaged with it's own separate distribution of Skia engine. But I really doubt that a set of functions and interfaces you want to share are really affecting overall application archive size so much, particularly taking into account Flutter's built-in tree shaking

Comment: Yeah, actually Google could roll-out something an optional Skia update for something for all Android versions devices so that Play Store install engine-independent apks for those devices...

Comment: Is it possible on a native level though?

Comment: I am not specializing in this particular area, but my assumption is: it's not. If I am not mistaken, all the code is being compiled and after that all the references are validated before [linking][1], whereas linker produces a single executable where all the code parts are related through some relative memory pointers that get transformed to a physical ones after loading the program into memory. But, it's mostly a guess that was given because no other answers were not given. Hopefully a specialist will catch this question soon :)

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)

Comment: Yeah...Assets can be stored in some common folder which can probably queried at runtime..but what about code and UI...Is it possible to safely get codes and Widgets from one Flutter application to the other or from a common "Base"/hidden-directory?

Comment: You will get data rather than code. In order to make this code in the string format work you will need to

1) Compile it
2) Link it to your main program

Which is, I'm afraid, impossible :(

But, again, I'm not an expert in this. It is, even quite confident, mostly a guess :)